# Drawing short and long lines with factor of over 1000 so that both are visible

Tags: canvas, graphics, lazarus

When drawing a line with length of 110.366 and another line of length 1.011 each angled at non-90 degree angle.  Let's say the lines are 60 degrees from each other and beginning of the lines are at the same point.  If I increase the scaling factor so the small line has a scale of 4 pixels then large line will be 440 pixels in length.  Also if I'm comparing several smaller lines such as 1.11, 1.22, and 1.33 they will appear to be the same length.  Is there a way i can get a higher resolution on the paint canvas so I can see small differences and long lines at the same time?

```
// Long line length 116.60317460 at angle of 312 degrees 
// Short line length 1.1111111 at angle of 240 degrees
// Start at point 200,204 at an angle of 68 degrees difference
MoveTo(200, 204);
LineTo(200 + 316, 204 - 348);
MoveTo(200, 204);
LineTo(200 - 4, 204 - 4);
```

Even at this, points are already being truncated to integers and the user is not getting accurate info when comparing lines that are close to length of 1.  x's and y's are determined by cosine and sine of given angles. Lines below two pixels are generally not visible. Lines that are longer can go off the screen and make it more difficult for the user to compare longer lines to get a sense of the graph. Scaling would probably help but I don't know of any.  I'm restricted to 3rd party shareware.

Answer (score 1):

If your lines all share a common point, use a logarithmic transform of the lengths to compress the range.

If they don't, you are kind of stuck.

Comment: Unfortunately the lines must be the correct ratio with each other so I am probably stuck with that.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @keterpstra_mwu: "the lines must be the correct ratio". Are you serious ?

Comment: I had placed one of the factors outside of the Truncate function so the other values would always resolve to zero.  Once the new factor was introduced in the Truncate function the lines began to appear better in the graph and were at least viewable.  I only noticed this when the xs and ys were always zero.  A couple of the tree graphs worked right so it was harder to detect.  Thanks for your help.